# Ajax success event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, webmethod, okta

Doing Okta Authentication on WebForms
The login works but the redirect part doesnt

I tried with void and to return json object/string but doenst work

if i delete contentType and dataType from ajax method the success event works but then i can't debbug the method and it wasn't doing what was suppose to do

My objective is at the end of the webmethod to redirect to SignedIn.aspx tried with this code but couldn't make it work either that's why im doing client side through ajax success method

```
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("SignedIn.aspx");
```

Ajax:

```
function FormSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Example.aspx/Login",
        data: "{hiddenSessionTokenField:'" + $('#hiddenSessionTokenField').val() + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Method Called Sucessfully" + response);
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/SignedIn.aspx";
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error " + response);
        }
    });
}
```

WebMethod

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void Login(string hiddenSessionTokenField)
        {

        //var result = new { url = "http://localhost:8080/SignedIn.aspx" };

        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
            properties.Dictionary.Add("sessionToken", hiddenSessionTokenField);
            properties.RedirectUri = "~/SignedIn.aspx";

            //Okta Authentication
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties,
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);


            //System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            //return s.Serialize(result));

        }
            //return s.Serialize(result));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#test').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "TEST.aspx/Login",
      data: "{hiddenSessionTokenField:'" + $('#hiddenSessionTokenField').val() + "'}",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (response) {
    //    alert("Method Called Sucessfully");
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/index.aspx";
   },
    error: function (response) {
      alert("error " + response);
       }
      });
     })


    public static void Login(string hiddenSessionTokenField) {
        int x = 0;

    }
```

Comment: Like i said i tried that more specifically like this HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("SignedIn.aspx");because the method is static i had to add HttpContext.Current but it doesnt do anything

Comment: Not sure if its a typo, but it needs to be Response.Redirect("~/SignedIn.aspx");

Comment: I did try exactly that with "~/SignedIn.aspx"  but like i said it doesn't work

Comment: Edited my answer with an example that works for me.

Comment: I need that in a static WebMethod

Comment: Got it to work as a static method. Updated answer with my code. Async false was not allowing the redirect.

Comment: That works, it was one of my experiments to try to make it work and actually forgot to delete it, thank you buddy